# When appending dictionary to a list, dict. not on a new line each time

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I have this function that pushes a dictionary created by another function, to a list. The problem I'm having with my code is that multiple pushes do not show up in the list each in a new line. I've tried many ways, but none have given me the desired results.

This is the line the pushes the created dictionary:

```
Database.xoomDatabase.append(ordenOrganiz)
```

This function creates the dictionary:

```
def orderZoom(self):
        nombre = contents1
        nicenum = orderResult
        email = contents2
        num = contents3
        fechaentrega = contents5

        global ordenOrganiz
        ordenOrganiz = {"Num Orden": nicenum,
                        "Nombre": nombre, 
                        "Email": email,
                        "Num Tel/Cel": num,
                        "Fecha de Entrega": fechaentrega}
        return ordenOrganiz
```

Any ideas on getting this done?

Comment: What do you mean by "not on a new line"? What is your expected output?

Comment: Why _would_ "multiple pushes [...] show up in the list each in a new line"?  What do newlines have to do with lists?

Comment: By new lines I mean that when I append the dictionaries to the lists and print them, each one will show in a different line and not each one after the next in the same line. I new to python so I'm not sure if I'm expressing correctly what I want done.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your problem is not the inserts but rather the "pretty print" that you want to apply, check out the following example that uses `json.dumps`:

```
import json

ordenOrganiz = {"Num Orden": 1,
                "Nombre": 2, 
                "Email": 3,
                "Num Tel/Cel": 4,
                "Fecha de Entrega": 5}
lst = []
lst.append(ordenOrganiz)                
lst.append(ordenOrganiz)                

print json.dumps(lst, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[
    {
        "Fecha de Entrega": 5,
        "Nombre": 2,
        "Num Tel/Cel": 4,
        "Num Orden": 1,
        "Email": 3
    },
    {
        "Fecha de Entrega": 5,
        "Nombre": 2,
        "Num Tel/Cel": 4,
        "Num Orden": 1,
        "Email": 3
    }
]
```

Comment: is there a way to use this to format is rows, as in:
 {"Fecha de Entrega": 5, "Nombre": 2, "Num Tel/Cel": 4,"Num Orden":1,"Email": 3 },  in one row etc..?

Comment: @JasonBK not sure if I got your intention correctly, if you want all in the same line you can do: `print(json.JSONEncoder().encode(lst))`

Comment: that prints to one single line, I need each object within {} to be a separate line (new line at comma basically) @alfasin

Comment: @JasonBK then you'll have to iterate the objects and print each one of the separately.

Comment: yes, that's what I cant get to work correctly @alfasin

Comment: `for x in lst print json.dumps(x, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))` ?

Comment: nope, prints out in the same block style as above..thanks anyway @alfasin

Comment: @JasonBK try: `for x in lst: print json.dumps(x)`

Comment: thanks, that works within the console (it prints in the format I am looking for) - but when I try to write to a file using :
for x in json_list:
    file(JSON_PATH, 'w').write(json.dumps(x))
it overwrites itself and leaves only the final line..any idea how i can use this to write to a json file? @alfasin

Comment: Please post a question with the code you're using, make sure to show the actual result vs. expected result and if you don't get help within 5 mins feel free to tag me there

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008753/csv-to-json-with-python-json-in-rows