# csv to json with python, json in rows

Tags: json, python-2.7, csv, format

I would like to covert a CSV to a set of JSON objects with Python, formatted in rows.

I tried this script below, put together from a couple SO answers, but this formats this way:

```
{
   key:'value'
},
{
   key:'value'
} // etc
```

I would like to format this as:

```
{ key, 'value'},
{ key, 'value'}, // etc
```

I tried a few ways suggested here to insert a newline, but none worked so far.

script below:

```
import sys, getopt
import csv
import json


CSV_PATH = 'path/file.csv'
JSON_PATH = 'path/demo.json'

csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_PATH, 'r'))

json_list = []
for row in csv_file:
   json_list.append(row )

file(JSON_PATH, 'w').write(json.dumps(json_list, indent=4, separators=(' ,')  ))
```

my csv is straightforward:

```
SUM_F   SUM_I   SUM_P   SUM_PI  SUM_Bt  SUM_BI  SUM_M   SUM_MI  Year    Month
15       3963     14      993    0      91      1      2879     2009       1
```

etc..

EDIT: I received this suggestion in the comments of another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929275/when-appending-dictionary-to-a-list-dict-not-on-a-new-line-each-time):

```
for x in json_list: print json.dumps(x)
```

this will print the format I am looking for, but I have not yet figured out how to write this to a json file.

Comment: I'd try but I can't figure out how mimic the contents of your `file.csv`, would you mind posting a few sample lines from it to show its structure?

Comment: @downshift I edited my question, its pretty straightforward

Comment: thanks, you're right that format is pretty straightforward. Try using `separators=(' ,\n')` works for me.

Comment: if I type as you have it there i bget a 'ValueError: too many values to unpack' message..if I put the comma and endline in quotes (' ,', '\n') the json has a new line at every string @downshift

Comment: my fault yes you're right, sorry about not noticing that, I had used two separators, with the newline included with the comma, so in full `file(JSON_PATH, 'w').write(json.dumps(json_list, separators=(' ,\n', ':')  ))`. I removed the `indent` parameter based on this "note" in the [json docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage): "Note: Since the default item separator is `', '`, the output might include trailing whitespace when *indent* is specified. You can use `separators=(',', ': ')` to avoid this."

Comment: @downshift no luck, the first line you have ( ' ,\n', ':') breaks in  into blocks (each key value on a separate line) and the second (',', ': ') outputs all in one line.

Comment: again sorry about that, I could never reproduce the original format you were getting..

Comment: @downshift no worries, see my edit above...that line will print in the format I want, but I cant figure out how to make this work writing to a file

Comment: thanks but sorry, I'll pass, I trust user alfasin will be able to solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import csv
import json

CSV_PATH = 'file.csv'
JSON_PATH = 'demo.json'

with open(CSV_PATH, 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    with open(JSON_PATH, 'w') as json_file:
        for row in reader:
            json_file.write(json.dumps(row) + '\n')
```

`str(row)` gives the wrong kind of quotes, don't use it. You won't be able to read the file with `json`.

Comment: this gives me no output.

Comment: that worked thanks. I did need to insert a comma before the line break for my web code to work,  which results in one extra comma at the end but it doesnt seem to affect anything.  You can edit that other post I have with this comment if you like.  @Alex Hall

Comment: @JasonBK I don't know what you're doing in your web code but it sounds really weird. I would just delete the other question.

Comment: my web code is not weird,  it's very simple and works well when the formatting is correct..I used this online tool before which also formats the JSONs in the same way http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/

Comment: @JasonBK which one of those formats do you consider the same as this code?

Answer (score 1):

First, the CSV file is not formatted properly, I had to reformat file.csv to look like:

```
SUM_F,SUM_I,SUM_P,SUM_PI,SUM_Bt,SUM_BI,SUM_M,SUM_MI,Year,Month
15,3963,14,993,0,91,1,2879,2009,1
3,4,5,6,0,971,1,8,9,10
```

in order to make it work - I'm not sure if that's the uneven number of spaces between the tokens or other reason.

Second, I modified the code:

```
import sys, getopt
import csv
import json


CSV_PATH = '/path/file.csv'
JSON_PATH = '/path/demo.json'

csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_PATH, 'r'))

f = file(JSON_PATH, 'w')
for row in csv_file:
    f.write(str(row)+"\n")
```

and the result (file) looks like:

```
{'SUM_I': '3963', 'SUM_M': '1', 'SUM_BI': '91', 'Month': '1', 'SUM_MI': '2879', 'SUM_F': '15', 'Year': '2009', 'SUM_Bt': '0', 'SUM_P': '14', 'SUM_PI': '993'}
{'SUM_I': '4', 'SUM_M': '1', 'SUM_BI': '971', 'Month': '10', 'SUM_MI': '8', 'SUM_F': '3', 'Year': '9', 'SUM_Bt': '0', 'SUM_P': '5', 'SUM_PI': '6'}
```

Comment: this worked for smaller csvs but for larger csvs it created a malformed JSON, it ended in  the middle of a row for some reason..the answer below seemed to work for those cases as well..but I appreciate the answer @alfasin