# csv to json script results in malformed json

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a short script to create json files from a csv.
The script seems to work well with smaller csvs, but with a larger csv (with a couple hundred rows, about 12 properties) the last created json seems to just stop in the middle of a json, with no closing bracket

Script below:

```
import sys, getopt
import csv
import json
CSV_monthly = 'my\path.csv'
JSON_monthly = 'another\path.json'

csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(CSV_monthly, 'r'))
f = file(JSON_monthly, 'w')
for row in csv_file:
   f.write(str(row)+",\n")
```

Comment: You shouldn't be writing JSON with the csv library. Use the json library instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your loop with `json.dump(list(csv_file), f)`.

Never encode JSON manually.

`str(row)` is not the same as JSON. JSON always uses double quotes. Python tries to use single quotes which are invalid JSON.

Use `with` statements to handle files.

Use `open` to open files, not `file`.

Comment: Suggest you add a complete code snippet to your answer showing all the changes.

Comment: my script came from an answer to another Q on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008753/csv-to-json-with-python-json-in-rows  the script above seems to work fine with a smaller csv.

Comment: I also don't think the above post is an answer so much as a few suggestions

Comment: @JasonBK the first point is the answer, the next two are closely related. I have no idea how your code is supposed to work at all. For example you complain that it leaves out the closing bracket, but your code has no mention of closing brackets, or opening brackets for that matter. Plus the trailing comma is invalid and your quotes are almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @JasonBK also you don't close your output file, that might be why it looks incomplete. Another reason to use a `with` statement.

Comment: @AlexHall see the link in my comments